# flutter_pagewise loads all images at once instead of lazyloading

Tags: flutter, dart

I'm using Flutter with the package `flutter_pagewise` to add lazyloading to a large image grid which loads images from local assets.

I created `json` file which includes all paths for the images. With this file I want to work as future source in `flutter_pagewise`.

**The function which returns the list from json for pagewise**

```
Future<List> getDemoImagesJson(int offset, int limit) async {
  String demoImages = await DefaultAssetBundle.of(context)
      .loadString("assets/demo/demo.json");

  final jsonResult = json.decode(demoImages);
  List images = [];
  for (var i in jsonResult) {
    images.add({"id": 1, "title": "sample", "thumbnailUrl": i});
  }

  final list = List.from(images).toList();
  var listWithOffset = list.skip(offset).toList();
  final finalList = listWithOffset.getRange(0, limit).toList();
  return ImageModel.fromJsonList(finalList);
}
```

**The ImageModel class (copied from official documentation)**

```
class ImageModel {
  String title;
  String id;
  String thumbnailUrl;

  ImageModel.fromJson(obj) {
    this.title = obj['title'];
    this.id = obj['id'].toString();
    this.thumbnailUrl = obj['thumbnailUrl'];
  }

  static List<ImageModel> fromJsonList(jsonList) {
    return jsonList.map<ImageModel>((obj) => ImageModel.fromJson(obj)).toList();
  }
}
```

**The PageWise Widget**

```
PagewiseGridView.count(
  shrinkWrap: true,
  physics: ClampingScrollPhysics(),
  pageSize: 10,
  crossAxisCount: 3,
  mainAxisSpacing: 8.0,
  crossAxisSpacing: 8.0,
  padding: EdgeInsets.all(15.0),
  itemBuilder: (context, entry, index) {
    return Container(
        child: Image.asset(entry.thumbnailUrl,
            fit: BoxFit.cover));
  },
  pageFuture: (pageIndex) {
    return getDemoImagesJson(pageIndex * 10, 10);
  })
```

**What I expect**: I expect that the Widget loads only 10 images and after I scroll down to the end of the page it loads other 10 images...until all images did load.

**What I get**: The Widget loads all images at once (as batch). There is no lazyload effect after reaching the bottom of the page.

Where is the issue?